# Text saved in DB as html code instead of the rendered text

Tags: html, asp.net, gridview

I am reading from a Gridview and write the results to a repeater, where that data is processed through a click event of a LinkButton and finally written to an SQL Table. For some reason the text is saved as HTML code and not as the rendered text.

> T&#233;st with s&#252;mbols

This would be what is saved if the Gridview row would display:

> Tést with sümbols

This must be due to the reading from the Gridview as my test proves, where I manually add a row (NameX) that then is displayed in the repeater. If I click on that entry the data written to the SQL Table is the rendered text.

```
protected void FillRepeater()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView4_Users.Rows)
    {
        if(row.Cells[3].Text != "0")
        {
            string Name = row.Cells[0].Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(Name);
        }
    }
    string NameX = "Tést with sümbols";
    dt.Rows.Add(NameX);
    RepeaterUsers.DataSource = dt;
    RepeaterUsers.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: @user685590 Please post your helpful comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string Name = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[0].Text);
```

forces that the rendered text is saved correctly to the string Name and hence to the database.

This solution had been posted by @user685590 as a comment and later deleted as part of over-moderation (sorry for that slight criticism)